# SDK/API barcode scanner without focus

Tags: api, sdk, barcode-scanner

Is there a USB barcode scanner/software that has an SDK/API that doesn't just use a keyboard emulator to input the data it scans? Like, when someone scans a barcode, have it process that information in the background without the need to have a program focused on a textbox or something.

Any links/advice would be great! :o)

Comment: Any specific OS or brand of scanner? Webcam based scanner or laser?

Comment: @emb1995: windows xp with a laster scanner. The DS6708-DL so i can scan US driver licences. Though i am not able to find any VB.net code? Have you seen any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Motorola's devices](http://www.motorola.com/Business/US-EN/Business+Product+and+Services/Bar+Code+Scanning/Bar+Code+Scanners/General+Purpose+Scanners?pMotFeatures=18) (formerly Symbol Technologies), They have corded USB units and I know they do have a non-KB-wedge SDK/API you can use from .NET, not sure what other languages they support.

The other main company you could check out would be [Honeywell's products](http://honeywell.com/Products-Services/Pages/scanning-mobile-productivity.aspx) (formerly HandHeld Products). It's been a while since I've used Honeywell's, as they tend to be more expensive and so most of our clients go the Motorola route. For that reason, I am not as sure about whether their SDK currently supports background scanning, though I would think it should.

Comment: No problem; just FYI if you go with them, in the Motorola .NET SDK their libraries don't do any graceful cleanup or GC, so you need to be sure to close the scanner yourself when you're done with it (unless they've recently addressed this issue). Other language SDKs may be the same.

Comment: Do you mean that after each scan i will need to reset the scanner in order for it to scan another bar code?

Comment: I don't think you needed to do that; no, I just mean like before you close/dispose your form/class/module, you need to be sure to close the scanner.

Comment: I bought the DS6708-DL so i can scan US driver licences. Though i am not able to find any VB.net code? Have you seen any?

Comment: Well, you need to start by downloading the SDK if you haven't already. You can find that on Motorola's site here: http://bit.ly/jGj5AP. Specifically, it looks like for .NET you need to download this one: http://bit.ly/kAUT1s, which is the Scanner SDK, the Driver's License SDK seems to be specific for C or C++. The release notes (http://bit.ly/mogMHO) for the `Scanner SDK` says it should include some .NET examples.

Answer (score 1):

Motorola Scanner SDK http://MotorolaSolutions.com/WindowsSDK capable of receiving barcode data as events in non-KB-wedge modes. There are C++ and C# sample applications comes with this SDK. You just needs to register for barcode events and implements a handler for that.